# Destructor is causing runtime error in C++

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, operator-keyword

I wrote class Complex using pointers and new keyword for allocating memory in heap. I overloaded + operator and = operator also. Everyting works fine until i use destructor to free allocated memory. Destructor is causing runtime error in Visual Studio.
. i think it is something related to deallocating memory on heap that is causing this problem. Run the code on Visual Studio. I also noticed that problem of destructor is associated with overloaded + operator. Please help me to overcome this issue. In VS

I am attaching image of error , produced by Visual Studio

[image]

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Complex {
private:
    int *real;
    int *complex;
    
public:
    // some declarations
    Complex();
    Complex(int, int);
    Complex operator+ (const Complex& rhs);
    Complex& operator= (const Complex& rhs);
    void disp() {
        cout << "(" << *real << "," << *complex << ")" << endl;
    }
    // destructor
    ~Complex() {
        delete real;
        real = nullptr;
        delete complex;
        complex = nullptr;
    }
    
};

// overloading + operator
Complex Complex::operator+ (const Complex &rhs) {
    int a, b;
    a = *(this->real) + *(rhs.real);
    b = *(this->complex) + *(rhs.complex);
    Complex temp(a,b);
    return temp;
}
// overloading = operator
Complex& Complex::operator= (const Complex& rhs) {
    
    *(this->real) = *(rhs.real);
    *(this->complex) = *(rhs.complex);
    return *this;

}
// no-args constructor
Complex::Complex() {
    real = new int;
    *real = 0;
    complex = new int;
    *complex = 0;
}
// parameterized constructor
Complex::Complex(int x,int y) : Complex() {
    
    *real = x;
    *complex = y;
}


int main() {
    Complex n1(5,-9);
    Complex n2(2, -1);
    Complex n3;
    n3= n1 + n2;
    n3.disp();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `Complex` class does not obey the rule of 3/5/0. The implicitly generated copy and move constructors and copy and move assignment operators are not correct. But there is no benefit to dynamically allocating your members here. Use should be using `int real;` and `int complex;` instead.

Comment: Why not just use [std::complex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex)?

Comment: i understand that you want to exercise using pointer. The problem is that this case is no use-case for pointers. Actually I don't know a good case to practice pointers, there are really more important things to learn. The most important thing you need to know about raw pointers is that you almost never need them

Comment: Good practice for pointers is using linked lists or graphs. Here it is completely inappropriate. You're using 12 bytes to store a 4 byte `int`.

Comment: Dependency injection is also a good use for pointers. If your class has external dependencies (hopefully setup with an abstract base class). Initialize them outside of your class and pass pointers (hopefully smart ones ;) ) in for your class to utilize. Very good use-case for